# Join tables efficiency on Linq

Tags: linq, xamarin.android

I'm beginner in Linq and I have observed that my inner join query is slower and less efficient than, for example, crossing the tables in code. Furthermore, these data charged in a ListView are much lighter.

Here is the code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Alumno> GetItems() 
{
        return (from gal in me.Table<GrupoAlumno>()
                join alu in me.Table<Alumno>()
                on gal.IdAlumno equals alu.ID
                select alu);
}
```

How is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `me.Table<GrupoAlumno>()` and `me.Table<Alumno>()`? What exactly does it return? Could you also show us the code that is faster?

Comment: -1 incomprehensible question.  My first question (with many more following): Are you using LinqToSql or LinqToObjects?

Comment: Excuse me for my english. I don't know the difference between the two. In any case, the question is solved. Thanks

Comment: Do note you may find yourself with repeated `Alumno` records if an `Alumno` belongs to more than one `GrupoAlumno`. You may need a `distinct` or `group by`. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: The reason that `ToList()` makes it faster is that your first linq query will be reevaluated *every single time* the results are iterated. With `ToList()` you cache the results in a list, which is faster.
If you've solved the problem yourself, please enter it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. It was necessary converting `toList()`, and now the data loading to my ListView works fine.

```
public static IEnumerable<Alumno> GetItems() 
{

        return (from gal in me.Table<GrupoAlumno>()
                join alu in me.Table<Alumno>()
                on gal.IdAlumno equals alu.ID
                select alu).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the existing accepted answer!

Linq does not just operate on `IEnumerable<T>` - it can also operate on `IQueryable<T>` and when it does then the Linq statement is often executed in a query language such as SQL. In this case, Linq is very similar in performance to operating directly in SQL, but has other advantages like Compile time type checking and intellisense.

I would agree with @Anders that whenever you are facing performance issues then measuring what is happening is a good first step - but I'd definitely disagree about "linq is probably not the way to go" - I'd say the opposite - "linq is probably the way to go" but please do make sure you measure and understand what is happening - just as with SQL, it's all too easy for your linq query to be doing something you really didn't expect!

Comment: I assumed that OP was asking about linq-to-objects, so that's the context of my answer. Linq-to-something which uses `IQueryable<T>` is a completely other story regarding performance.

Comment: Understood :) I was just a little cautious because it contained `Table<T>` which made me thinking OP must be using SQLite... but something tells me we'll never find out the truth :)

Answer (score 0):

Linq operators works on `IEnumerable<T>`, so it can make now assumptions about the data being sorted, nor can it utilize any better ways to access data than simply looping through it.

When the amounts of data increases it is often possible to write much more efficient code using other constructs that take advantage of how the underlying data store and other known facts about the data.

If performance is a problem (did you profile your code to verify that this is indeed a problem?), then linq is probably not the way to go. I think that linq is terrific to express searches and manipulation of data when performance is less important than the time it takes to implement. If it is the other way around, linq might be too slow for you.